# Uber sample Google maps JS API

Tags: javascript, cordova, google-maps

I tried to use any of the snippets of code to choose the shortest marker to my current location so that I can send him/her a message but I couldn't understand any of them. 
So I wrote my own one,it gives me a right answer but I'm worried if it would be working good with a lot of markers or not .

here it is :

```
// data 
            var json1 = [
                {
                    "id": "34324"
                    , "title": "Stockholm"
                    , "lat": 59.3
                    , "lng": 18.1
                    , "description": "Stockholm is the capital and the largest city of Sweden"
      }
                        , {
                    "id": "4343212"
                    , "title": "Oslo"
                    , "lat": 59.9
                    , "lng": 10.8
                    , "description": "Oslo is a municipality, and the capital and most populous city of Norway"
      }
    ]
            var tempArray = json1;
            var resultsarray = [];
            for (var i = 0; i < tempArray.length; i++) {
                var xx = json1[i];
                var point = new plugin.google.maps.LatLng(xx.lat, xx.lng);
                var distance = plugin.google.maps.geometry.spherical.computeDistanceBetween(MyLocation, point);
                resultsarray.push(distance);
            };
            var min = Math.min.apply(Math, resultsarray);
            var b = 0;
            for (var e = 0; e < resultsarray.length; e++) {
                if (resultsarray[e] == min) {
                    b = e;
                    break;
                }
            };
            var theshortestone = tempArray[b];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To calculate the distance between to points (without using Maps API) you can use the [Haversine Formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Haversine_formula)

Distance function:

```
function getDistance(lat1, lon1, lat2, lon2) {
    var R = 6371; // Radius of the earth in km
    var dLat = deg2rad(lat2-lat1);  // deg2rad below
    var dLon = deg2rad(lon2-lon1);
    var a = Math.sin(dLat/2) * Math.sin(dLat/2) +
            Math.cos(deg2rad(lat1)) * Math.cos(deg2rad(lat2)) *
            Math.sin(dLon/2) * Math.sin(dLon/2);
    var c = 2 * Math.atan2(Math.sqrt(a), Math.sqrt(1-a));
    var d = R * c; // Distance in km
    return d;
}

function deg2rad(deg) {
    return deg * (Math.PI/180)
}
```

Your code:

```
var yourLat = 60.3,
    yourLong = 58.2;

for (var i = 0; i < tempArray.length; i++) {
    var xx = json1[i];
    var distance = getDistance(yourLat, yourLong,  xx.lat, xx.lng);
    resultsarray.push(distance);
};
```

Comment: what about me one ? is it good ? what do you think about it ?

Comment: @BishoyWadie I think that it depends on the amount of data that you need to process. For instance, you can improve the performance of your script removing the call to Google Maps API inside your loop and using the distance function instead but at the end all depends on how you are going to use it.